# "undefined reference" for lambda function to process multiple template classes

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

I have an template class like this:

`Strip.h`

```cpp
#pragma once

class IStrip
{
public:
    int Pin;

    void compute();
};

template <int PIN>
class Strip : public IStrip
{
public:
    int Pin = PIN;

    void compute()
    {

    }
};
```

and I manage multiple instances of them like so:

`Manager.h`

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "Strip.h"

class Manager
{
private:
    Strip<12> inst12;
    Strip<13> inst13;

    template <typename Func>
    void each(Func f)
    {
        f(inst12);
        f(inst13);
    }

    void computeData()
    {
        each([](IStrip sm)
             { sm.compute(); });
    }
};
```

Now, whenever I call `computeData()`, I'd like to apply some logic to all of my instances, as seen in `each(Func f)`, however, whenever I compile, I receive:

```
.pio\main.cpp.o:(.literal._ZN6Strips4loopEv[Strips::loop()]+0x14): undefined reference to `IStrip::compute()'
.pio\main.cpp.o: In function `Strips::computeData()::{lambda(IStrip*)#1}::operator()(IStrip*) const':
.pio\libdeps\az-delivery-devkit-v4\FastLED\src/controller.h:171: undefined reference to `IStrip::compute()'
```

When i change the function body of `computeData` to:

```cpp
each([](auto sm)
     { sm.compute(); });
```

and compile using `-std=gnu++14`, it magically works, however, the program just halts without exception when trying to call `compute()`.

Am I missing an important detail? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing quite a lot. First of all the `IStrip` class or the `Strip` class template are not polymorphic. And by passing `sm` by value to the lambda, you have object *slicing*.

To make it work, you first of all need to make `IStrip::compute` a pure virtual function:

```
class IStrip
{
public:
    virtual void compute() = 0;
};
```

Then you need to pass the object by reference to the lambda function:

```
each([](IStrip& sm)
         { sm.compute(); });
```

The `Strip::compute` function needs to be pure, otherwise you must define (implement) it.

---

What happens now with your current code is that you attempt to call `IStrip::compute()`, which is indeed not defined (implemented).

And what happens when you use `auto` argument deduction is that the compiler deduces that you pass an `Strip<X>` object, which have its `compute` function defined.

Comment: Thanks for the additional details about `auto`. I have tried to use virtual from the start, however some other part of my application was stopping the exceution and I falsely assumed it was because of that. I'm still trying to understand certain syntactical parts as I've only started cpp a few days ago. Well deserved accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt leads to undefined behavior.

```
class IStrip
{
public:
    int Pin;

    void compute();
};
```

declares `IStrip::compute()` function, but never defines it. Later on, when lambda

```
    each([](IStrip sm)
         { sm.compute(); });
```

is called, you end up `slicing` `Strip` object to `ISlip` and trying to call function which was never defined - hence, you have undefined reference issue.

A best solution to this problem, which would allow early detection and meaningful diagnostic, would be to declare `IStrip::compute()` as pure virtual.

Compiler would alert you of an attempt to create an instance of abstract class, which would prompt you to change lambda to

```
    each([](IStrip& sm)
         { sm.compute(); });
```